# Diagonal union of non-stationary sets

Tags: set-theory

I have a family of non-stationary sets $A_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha < \kappa,\ A_{\alpha}\subset\kappa$. The exercise is to show that $\triangledown A_{\alpha}$ is also non-stationary.

I've been thinking of a solution as to construct a club set which the diagonal intersection does not... intersects, but this didn't lead me anywhere. Then I thought of a proof by contradiction using Fodor's lemma, but I don't see any condtradiction in assuming $\triangledown A_{\alpha}$ in fact is stationary...

Please, help.

Comment: That's odd. Diagonal intersection of *clubs* is a club; diagonal *union* of non-stationary is non-stationary.

Comment: Oh my, the exercise has an inverted triangle there, I didn't notice! I'll make an edit, cause I still don't know the solution...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I mean, the diagonal *intersection* of nonstationary sets is also nonstationary, it's just less exciting. :P

Comment: Just a hint maybe then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $A_\alpha$ non-stationary. Then there are clubs $C_\alpha\subseteq \kappa$ such that $A_\alpha \cap C_\alpha =\emptyset$. Now the club
$$
C:= \Delta_{\alpha<\kappa} C_\alpha
$$
doens't intersect $\nabla_{\alpha<\kappa} A_\alpha$. To see this, simply observe that the latter set is the complement in $\kappa$ of $\Delta_{\alpha<\kappa} (\kappa\setminus A_\alpha)$. Now
$$
C \cap \nabla_{\alpha<\kappa} A_\alpha = C \setminus \Delta_{\alpha<\kappa} (\kappa\setminus A_\alpha).
$$
But $\Delta_{\alpha<\kappa} (\kappa\setminus A_\alpha)\supseteq \Delta_{\alpha<\kappa} C_\alpha= C$ (since diagonal intersection is *monotone*), and we're done.